# Is C# compiler not reporting all errors at once at each compile?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

When I am compiling this project, it show like 400+ errors in the Error List window, then I go to error sites, fix some, and the number goes to say 120+ errors, and then after fixing some more, the next compile reports like 400+ again. I can see that different files are coming in in the Error List window, so I am thinking the compiler aborts after a certain number of errors?

If so, what's the reason for this? Is it not supposed to gather all the errors that are present in the project even if they are over 10K+?

Comment: Often, fixing some errors brings other errors into focus. It's not easy to tell that a car has a low-fuel problem *until* you fix the broken-fuel-gauge problem.

Comment: @Ani: Thanks, I know the ones you mean, but most of the errors are syntax errors in different files and most of them are ignored by file from what I can tell.

Comment: Perhaps the more significant question is why do you have 400+ errors?

Comment: @abelenky, that could easily be done by forgetting to include some library.

Comment: @abelenky: lol, they aren't my errors. Just some project they asked me to fix and make compilable.

Comment: @Filip: as she said she fixes some errors, then gets more, it sounds like more than a #include / using problem.  @Joan: good to know the problem didn't originate with you.  Sounds like it may be a candidate for thedailywtf.com

Comment: @abelenky, could be a good story for sure. Btw on a side note, I am not a she :O

Comment: @joan: my apologies.  I have several female friends named "Joan", and made an improper assumption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been meaning to write a blog article about this.

It is possible that you're simply running into some hard-coded limit for the number of errors reported. It's also possible that you're running into a more subtle and interesting scenario.

There are a lot of heuristics in the command-line compiler and the IDE compiler that attempt to manage error reporting. Both to keep it manageable for the user, and to make the compiler more robust.

Briefly, the way the compiler works is it tries to get the program through a series of stages, which you can read about here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx

The idea is that if an early stage gets an error, we might not be able to successfully complete a later stage without (1) going into an infinite loop, (2) crashing, or (3) reporting crazy "cascading" errors. So what happens is, you get one error, you fix it, and then suddenly the next stage of compilation can run, and it finds a bunch more errors.

Basically, if the program is so messed up that we cannot even verify basic facts about its classes and methods, then we can't reliably give errors for method bodies. If we can't analyze a lambda body, then we can't reliably give errors for its conversion to an expression tree. And so on; there are lots of situations where later stages need to know that the previous stages completed without errors.

The up side of this design is that (1) you get the errors that are the most "fundamental" first, without a lot of noisy, crazy cascading errors, and (2) the compiler is more robust because it doesn't have to try to do analysis on programs where the basic invariants of the language are broken. The down side is of course your scenario: that you have fifty errors, you fix them all, and suddenly fifty more appear.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Just saw this. Makes perfect sense. By cascading errors do you mean like if a bracket is missing, it can report many many errors resulting from it, like some methods would be reported outside the class, etc when the closing bracket of a preceding method is missing?

Answer (score 6):

Of course it will stop at some point.

Even after 1 error, all the rest is dubious at best. A compiler will try to recuperate, but that's not guaranteed to succeed.

So in any non-trivial project, it's a practical decision between stopping at the first error (theoretically the best thing to do) and ploughing on in an unreliable state.

The most correct action would be to stop after 1 error, but that would lead to a tedious 'fix 1 at a time' situation. So a compiler tries to resync to a known state and report the next one. But an error could cause false errors in correct code following it, so at some point it stops being sensible.

Refer to your own case: 400+ goes to 120 after a few fixes.

Comment: Thanks, why did you say "formally"? Not anymore?

Comment: Got it, but in that case doesn't it show the robustness of the compiler?

Comment: This is not really about robustness but about being practical. After the first error there is no solid ground anymore.

Comment: But what if the programmer wants to assess how bad the project code is? Like if it has 100K+ errors, one can say it's very broken. Or do you mean "there is no solid ground anymore" for the compiler?

Comment: Also while I fix one area, I see hundreds of red lines, so when I re-implement it, I erase the area which makes me believe that I just fixed a hundred.

Comment: The latter. Anything after error #1 is heuristic. It usually gives valuable info but you could probably construct code where 1 typo generates 100s of errors.

Comment: @Joan: If you want to assess how bad a program is, fix all errors and then assess it.  If a programmer is giving you code that already has compiler errors, something is very wrong! Under normal circumstances, code with compiler errors should be not shared (except in the context of talking about the errors themselves) with anyone beyond the individual trying to fix them, via source control or otherwise.

Comment: @Brian: I meant a pre-assessment to see if it worths to fix it or rewrite sort of thing.

Comment: @Joan: I repeat my original statement: If a programmer is giving you code that already has compiler errors, something is very wrong! So, I would ask the question, "why is this guy giving me code with compiler errors?" If the answer is, "he *never* tries to compile his code while working on it," then I question his ability to code.

Comment: Yes I know, it's bad but what can I do. Some people get away with this sort of things :O

Answer (score 1):

It's configurable according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980440.aspx)

> By default, the maximum number is 200 errors and warnings.

Comment: Just tried it but didn't do anything, also it says this is for db projects though.

Comment: @Joan, Noticed that now, it's relevant to Visual Studio though so maybe I should keep the answer?

Comment: For sure, I think it's still useful to some.